# Правильность сочетания "один из самых больших выборов обуви"

Tags: грамматика

Скажите, пожалуйста, как будет правильно: "один из самых больших ВЫБОРОВ обуви" или "один из самых больших ВЫБОР обуви"?

По словарю *"выбор"* — склоняемое слово, но склонять в значении "ассортимент" (вроде два ассортимента), странновато, да и так сближается с политическими выборами...

Заранее спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: Я бы написала так: [Наш или у нас] *Выбор обуви — один из самых больших.*

Comment: Когда я прочитал вопрос, не ощутил никакого диссонанска, никакой отсылки к выборам как политическому событию.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большущее!